# cURL headers not being applied

Tags: php, curl, header, content-type

I have the following cURL syntax in PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type: application/json',
                                            'Connection: Keep-Alive',
                                            'account:A004',
                                            'key : 1234-12'
                                            ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $request=  curl_getinfo($ch);
    var_dump($request);

echo "<br><br><br>Reply:";
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
```

This works partially as I get a result from my server but the correct headers arent being sent so the server is not replying with any data. the output is:

```
array(22) 
 {
   ["url"]=> string(94) "https://api.domain.com/v1/config/limits"
   ["content_type"]=> NULL
   ["http_code"]=> int(0)
   ["header_size"]=> int(0)
   ["request_size"]=> int(0) 
   ["filetime"]=> int(0) 
   ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
   ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
   ["total_time"]=> float(0) 
   ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0) 
   ["connect_time"]=> float(0) 
   ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0)
   ["size_upload"]=> float(0)
   ["size_download"]=> float(0)
   ["speed_download"]=> float(0)
   ["speed_upload"]=> float(0)
   ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1)
   ["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1)
   ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0)
   ["redirect_time"]=> float(0)
   ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { }
   ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) ""
 }
```

Reply:

```
   HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Server: nginx
   Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 14:46:26 GMT
   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
   Content-Length: 51
   Connection: keep-alive
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

   {"status":"failure ","data":"Authentication Error"}
```

Why are the headers not being set like content header and the key?

Thanks as always.

Comment: at least try to format your headers properly: `account:[space]A004`, and `key[nospacehere]: 1234-12`.

Comment: Looks fine to me. How did you establish the statement that the ehaders are not send? Have you dumped the request?

Comment: Thanks @Mark, just the spacing - frustrating! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple issue, frustratingly so. spacing

Just the formatting on the headers. 
'key : 1234-12'
should be 
'key: 1234-12'

Thanks for your time.